# Should i use parked domains or separate accounts in cpanel

Tags: cpanel

My question is is there any performance difference between:

1) 10 Parked domains and htaccess and php handling to what to load on same account

2) 10 separeate accounts

Users get same on front end, and i am currently using one account and all parked domain but i wonder if that slowing down my performance?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web hosting rather than programming.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming and programmers tools related questions, not questions about web hosting. The [help] and [about] pages can help clarify the types of questions that are appropriate here. Good luck.

Comment: It is related to programming also because i use programming to route parked domains to theirs applications

Comment: I keep having people here tell me to go elsewhere and people there telling me the question doesn't belong there either. I do not understand why I have to be insulted to get a technical question answered. I come here for answers to questions that arise while I am doing programming related tasks. the Wordpress site is the worst though. Someone there told me I wasn't competent to do my job when I was trying to secure my server! My apps use a server! I want it secure, so I ask what I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

There is no performance difference that I know of.

With separate accounts, cpanel basically creates different vhost entries to map domain name to their respective websites.

.htaccess mapping is pretty much the same thing with vhosts.

There is however an exception:

If the hosting company you are in uses CloudLinux OS, or anything to isolate each tenant to his environment, then you are only allowed a portion of server's CPU per account. That means the more sites you have in one account, the slower it gets (provided the sites are all actively handling requests and responses).

By the way, I think web hosting questions like this are perfectly valid here. Programmers have different needs too :)